# How to disable workspace trust in vscode-test?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I run test using `vscode-test` and the "Do you trust this workspace" message pops up. How do I disable it for my test execution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pass `--disable-workspace-trust` to `runTests`:

```typescript
await runTests({version,
  extensionDevelopmentPath,
  extensionTestsPath,
  launchArgs: [workspacePath, "--disable-workspace-trust"]
});
```